# Ajax content inserted in a div issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a slight issue when i get content using ajax. The issue is that once the success event trigger, i put the content loaded onto a div and call one function

```
$('.content').html(data);
$('.image').resize(function(e) { more code.... });
```

Well, the question is that when the second line is executed the content is not already ready, so it has no effect.

What can i do in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your resize function the same all the time or does it depend on the content?

Comment: Look into `queue()` - http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: The `resize` event only happens when the browser window is resized and is sent to the `window` object... http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the second line in a callback function and use .load to accomplish the first part:

```
$('.content').load(<ajax url here>, function () {
  $('.image').resize(function (e) {
    // do whatever else you need to do here
  });
});
```

Comment: I think that's the way to go, using ajax callbacks. I would say `$('.content').load(<ajax url here>, function (data) {
$('.content').html(data);  
$('.image').resize(function (e) {
    // do whatever else you need to do here
  });
});`

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that you are attaching events to things that aren't in the DOM yet (because of the AJAX load), you can use a delegated event handler.

This assumes that all the `.image` elements are inside the `.content` element(s). You can do:

```
$('.content').on('resize', '.image', function(e) { ... });
```

See the [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event registration syntax. This will listen for the `resize` event on all the `.image` elements in the `.content` element(s) even if they are added dynamically (i.e. via AJAX).